# How do I convert Image Path in excel to an image in PowerApps?

Tags: excel, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

[image]

I have set Path[image] column in the excel sheet as shown in the above image.

[image]

I wanted to convert this image path in the excel to an image and display it on the Media Image in Powerapps but the image did not appear.

Please do help me take a look at the problem I have encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this [community thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Add-Images-From-OneDrive-to-Gallery/td-p/158730), it says

> Notice that you have to have "[image]" inclued in your image column name to make PowerApps automantically show this column as a Picture control in the app.

Also check the prerequisites like cloud storage, image accessible path like [explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/add-images-to-excel).